# Modify Template in code-behind

Tags: wpf

In our app we use 3rd party library components.
I need to change only one value in whole template. How can I archieve this without redefine template?

For example, controlTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Border x:Name="PART_MainBorder"
                BorderBrush="Black" 
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <ContentPresenter/>
        </Border>            
</ControlTemplate>
```

I need to change `PART_MainBorder.BorderBrush`. How can I do this?

I have found [this link](http://siderite.blogspot.com/2010/12/cloning-controltemplate.html), but I can't believe there is no other way to do it..

Thanks.

Comment: Don't overcomplicate things. We have a huge WPF application, and while we wanted that option one or two times, we just did the "normal" way of creating a new template. And it never was a problem. What do you want to change on it? Create a template where each necessary property can be set outside. One nice way is to use a class with attached properties to further customize the used template/style. For example create a LabelStyleService and give it a BorderBrush attached property, now you can write <Label LabelStyleService.BorderBrush="Red" Template="{.../>

Comment: It isn't a good deсision for me, cause we have several themes, so I need to redefine 4 templates. 
I can do this, but is there another way?

Comment: Why do you have to define 4 Templates for 4 Themes? I'd do exactly what @dowhilefor suggested in replicating the Template once with your one line modification. Do not go down the route of `FindName()` or `LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(...)` just aint nice. Define 1 Template and in the Template copy everything fom the source lib that you don't want to change and for `BoderBrush` set `BorderBrush={DynamicResource SomeBrush}`. Now in each theme over-ride `SomeBrush` accordingly and your sorted.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do it in XAML but to answer your question template is nothing more but a cookie cuter so you cannot just start changing properties of template objects in code behind. You can modify template controls properties via control to which the template has been applied. In case of `ControlTemlate` it will be templated control and for `DataTemplate` it will be `ContentPresenter` used to generate content. So let's say that you have 2 `Labels` to which you applied template above:

```
<Label Content="A" x:Name="Label1"/>
<Label Content="B" x:Name="Label2"/>
```

an then in the code you can change `Border.BorderBrush` like this:

```
(Label1.Template.FindName("PART_MainBorder", Label1) as Border).BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
(Label2.Template.FindName("PART_MainBorder", Label2) as Border).BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
```

worth noting that 2 `Labels` will have **different** `BorderBrush` color

Comment: Thank you for answer, @dkozl! But here I need to set this property to every control in app... I just want chages apply to all controls of this type.

Comment: Template controls can only be modified via control to which it has been applied. If this is what you want to achieve then go with what @dowhilefor suggested in his comment.